# How to add mysql_real_escape_string to this code?

Tags: php, foreach

I am unsure as to how to add escape string to the `$_POST['scan']` I used

```
$var = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['scan']);
```

And then swapped it with the `$_POST['scan']` in the code but it won't work.  It just shows me blank screen.

```
foreach ($_POST['scan'] as $key => $value1) {
    echo "$value1, ";
}
```

Comment: We need more context to being able to accurately answer your question.

Comment: sure what you need to know more about this?

Comment: Is form object named `scan` a text field or something that will be an array, like several checkboxes or multiselect?

Comment: Is $_POST['scan'] an array? What is it that you actually want to do here?

Comment: If it's an array, then [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) could apply it to each element.

Comment: A Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example would be rather helpful, see http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_real_escape_string($str)` is used for escaping SQL queries, not for displaying to the user. You may like to use `htmlentities($str)` or `htmlspecialchars($str)` instead.

Comment: Then don't echo it in your example code but add some actual code.

Answer (score 0):

try:    print_r($_POST);

to see what you are getting in your post variables. Are you even passing an array via $_POST['scan'] or any data at all? As someone else alluded to, mysql_real_escape_string is to be used on a string prior to inserting into mysql, and hopefully after the string has been validated/sanitized.

Comment: Also, how do you want to insert the data into the DB? If as a string, you'll have to do some formatting first.